# Pythonで辞書同士を比較し同値性を確認したい

Tags: python

pythonでは2つの辞書を比較するのに `==` を使っても大丈夫でしょうか？
全てのkey, valueのペアが一致しているかどうかを調べたいです。

```
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c': 3}
dict2 = {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b':2}
print(dict1 == dict2)

dict3 = {'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c': 3}
dict4 = {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b':2.0}
print(dict3 == dict4)
```

printではどちらも `True` が返ってきました。
辞書でkeyの順序は関係ないのは分かります。
`2 == 2.0`が`True`で判定されるもの問題ないです。

例ではkeyを文字列、valueを数値にしていますが、valueがリストだったり辞書だったりした場合でも問題ないでしょうか？

```
import pickle
x = pickle.dumps(dict1)
y = pickle.dumps(dict2)
print(x == y)

p = pickle.dumps(dict3)
q = pickle.dumps(dict4)
print(p == q)
```

ちなみに`pickle.dumps()`でシリアライズをすると`x==y`は`True`になりましたが、`p==q`は`False`になりました。

Comment: 通常、「同一性」というと「同じオブジェクトであるかどうか」を指します。Pythonではこれを調べるのに [`is` 演算子](https://docs.python.jp/3/reference/expressions.html#is) が用意されています。今回の質問は「同じ値かどうか」に関してですので、タイトルの用語は「同値性」へ変更させていただきました。

Answer (score 7):

> valueがリストだったり辞書だったりした場合でも問題ないでしょうか？

リスト／辞書に対して再帰的に比較が行われるため、期待通りの振る舞いとなります。

Python(3.6)  The Python Language Reference [6.10.1. Value comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons)より引用：

> The following list describes the comparison behavior of the most important built-in types.
>
> - [...]
> - Sequences (instances of `tuple`, `list`, or `range`) can be compared only within each of their types, with the restriction that ranges do not support order comparison. Equality comparison across these types results in inequality, and ordering comparison across these types raises `TypeError`.
> - [...]
> - Mappings (instances of `dict`) compare equal if and only if they have equal *(key, value)* pairs. Equality comparison of the keys and elements enforces reflexivity.

---

> `pickle.dumps()`でシリアライズをすると`x==y`は`True`になりましたが、`p==q`は`False`になりました。

シリアライズ結果をみれば自明かと思いますが、`2`と`2.0`部分が異なるバイト列に変換されています。`p`, `q`は異なるバイト列のため同値ではありません（`p==q`の結果は`False`）。

また`x==y`が`True`になったのは**偶然**です。他のPython処理系では異なる結果になる可能性があります。手元で試したところCPython 3.6と3.5では結果が異なりました。これは[CPython 3.6で辞書型(`dict`)が順序を保持するように実装変更された](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2016-September/146348.html)ためと推測されますが、Python言語としては依然として「辞書型の順序保証はしない」ことになっています。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
`dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c': 3}`のシリアライズ結果を見るとa,b,cだったりa,c,bだったりキーの順序は毎度入れ替わっていたのですが、x==yの結果は毎度`True`でした。
Python2.7.13の環境で100回ほど試しました。
たぶん偶然だろうなとは思ったんですが、そうなると2つの辞書を'=='で比較したときに`True`になるのもたまたまなのか、仕様なのかを調べたかったんですが自力だと答えにたどり着けず質問させて頂きました。

Comment: 辞書型のキー順序は実際にはランダムではありません。"[Keys and values are iterated over in an arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)"。なので、残念ながら100回試すことにさほど意味はありません...